# Maximal function estimate for differential quotient of function satisfying $\nabla f \in BMO$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces

For a function $f \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^N)$, it is well-known that there exists a constant $C_N$ (dependent on $N$) such that
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| \le C_N|x-y|(\mathcal M|\nabla f|(x) + \mathcal M|\nabla f|(y)),
$$
where $\mathcal M$ is the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function.

How can this estimate be improved if we assume $f \in L^p(\mathbb R^N)$ and $\nabla f \in BMO(\mathbb R^N)$ instead of $f \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^N)$?

Comment: Can you explain why the above inequality is true in $W^{1,p}$?

Comment: I guess you forgot a factor $|x-y|$ on the RHS.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Yes, there was a typo